# Cycles render is transparent/grey irrespective of material

Tags: cycles-render-engine

just.... what is this please? Suddenly, even the basic Principled BSDF material looks like this in Cycles. Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, is it the same with a previous version of Blender?

Comment: Yes, I thought that maybe downloading new version 3.5. today would help, but it didn't...

Comment: Looks like there are no lights in the scene.  Check if there are lights and if they are enabled for rendering (camera icon in the outliner). Make sure that they aren't in a closed/deactivated collection. Do use an HDRI in the World Properties (http://i.stack.imgur.com/4FM70.png)? The default color is dark grey. -- And yes, it could be a bug/limitation. When I use complex shaders, the integrated GPU on my laptop no longer can handle dynamic lights and just turns them off until I restart Blender. Does it also happen when you render with Cycles on the CPU?

Comment: Strangely enough, the solution was to take everything a copy it to a new blender file ✔️. Thank you, guys, but I have still no clue what is happening... 
And yes, I was attempting to render in Cycles, have never experienced any problem before

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically the material is hidden. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, but since you are using a Mac that will be <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? How can a *material* be hidden? What do you have to select to reveal the hidden material?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not the case apparently. :( But thanks for trying to help.